# Intento cambiar apariencia de un botón añadiendo clase CSS mediante JS

Tags: javascript, html

Quiero que cuando haga click en el boton enviar, se marque el siguiente botón

Tengo 3 botones; usando la variable `iteracion`, que incrementa su valor cada vez que se presiona el enlace `enviar`, intento que cambie el estado de los botones agregando la clase `btn-primary` a cada uno de ellos, consecutivamente y según se incrementa el valor de la variable `iteracion`.

Necesito una solución sin usar librerias de JS.

```js
var iteracion=0; function modificar(estado){ var h2 = document.querySelectorAll(".stepwizard-row > .stepwizard-step >.btn"); for (hh of h2) { hh.classList.add('btn-default'); hh.classList.remove('btn-primary'); } var h1 = document.getElementById("stepwizard-row"); var hijo=h1.childNodes[estado]; var boton=hijo.childNodes[1]; boton.classList.add('btn-primary'); } $('#add-new-fact').click(function() { iteracion++; modificar(iteracion); });
```

```css
body{margin:40px;}

.stepwizard-step p {
    margin-top: 10px;    
}

.stepwizard-row {
    display: table-row;
}

.stepwizard {
    display: table;     
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.stepwizard-step button[disabled] {
    opacity: 1 !important;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100) !important;
}

.stepwizard-row:before {
    top: 14px;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    content: " ";
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    z-order: 0;
    
}

.stepwizard-step {    
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}

.btn-circle {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 6px 0;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.428571429;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
```

```html
<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">


 <div class="stepwizard">
    <div class="stepwizard-row" id="stepwizard-row">
        <div class="stepwizard-step">
            <button id="uno" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-circle">1</button>
            <p>Registro #1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="stepwizard-step">
            <button id="dos" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle">2</button>
            <p>Registro #2</p>
        </div>
        <div class="stepwizard-step">
            <button id="tres" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle">3</button>
            <p>Registro #3</p>
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>

<a id='add-new-fact' href='#'> enviar</a>
```

Comment: Seria bueno que te tomes el tiempo de explicar que problema tienes, pues asi no se entiende. No es solo cosa de copiar, pegar, escribir 2 palabras y presionar enviar. ¿para que esta el CSS? hay algun problema con eso? todo el HTML es necesario? .. intenta simplificar el ejemplo.

Comment: @EmanuelVe el css es necesario para ver el resultado, pero no es necesario revisarlo porque no es ahi el problema, el problema es en el js

Comment: Sigue siendo necesario que expliques qué necesitas hacer. Tu pregunta es muy críptica y no entiendo si acaso lo que quieres es que al presionar "enviar", el recuadro 2 tome color azul, y el recuadro 1 el color blanco. ¿Qué pasa cuando el 3 está azul y presiono enviar? ¿Se pone azul el primero?

Comment: @amenadiel cuando el 3 esta azul todos los demas deben ser blancos, cuando el 2 esta azul los demas deben ser blancos, cuando se pinta el 1 todos los demas deben ser blancos

Comment: ¿Ésto tienes que hacerlo necesariamente usando JS? Creo que basta con HTML / CSS3

Comment: @Orici si con js, no me serviria con css.

Answer (score 1):

Por lo que entendí, el primer botón parte en azul. Al presionar el link de abajo, se van activando el segundo y luego el tercer botón.

En mi código, hay un contador de iteraciones que parte en cero, y se va incrementando con cada click.

Cada click provoca dos efectos:

- Se ponen todos los botones en blanco
- El enésimo botón se pone en azul, donde N es la cantidad de iteraciones

Voy a pulirlo un poco para usar una función.

```js
var iteracion=0;

var activaBoton=function(posicion) {
  // ponemos todos los botones en blanco
  jQuery("#stepwizard-row")
       .find('button')
       .removeClass('btn-primary')
       .addClass('btn-default');
       
  // ponemos en azul el botón correspondiente a la posicion       
  jQuery("#stepwizard-row")
      .find('button')
      .eq(posicion)
      .addClass('btn-primary')
      .removeClass('btn-default');
};

activaBoton(iteracion);
        
$('#add-new-fact').click(function() {
    iteracion++;
    activaBoton(iteracion);
});
```

```css
body{margin:40px;}

.stepwizard-step p {
    margin-top: 10px;    
}

.stepwizard-row {
    display: table-row;
}

.stepwizard {
    display: table;     
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.stepwizard-step button[disabled] {
    opacity: 1 !important;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100) !important;
}

.stepwizard-row:before {
    top: 14px;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    content: " ";
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    z-order: 0;
    
}

.stepwizard-step {    
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}

.btn-circle {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 6px 0;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.428571429;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
```

```html
<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">


 <div class="stepwizard">
    <div class="stepwizard-row" id="stepwizard-row">
        <div class="stepwizard-step">
            <button id="uno" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-circle">1</button>
            <p>Registro #1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="stepwizard-step">
            <button id="dos" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle">2</button>
            <p>Registro #2</p>
        </div>
        <div class="stepwizard-step">
            <button id="tres" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle">3</button>
            <p>Registro #3</p>
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>

<a id='add-new-fact' href='#'> enviar</a>
```

Comment: funciona!!! pero queria en js puro, lo convertire, en la edicion de alguien puso jquery.

Comment: @hubman fallo mío lo de jQuey! Vi la línea:
$('#add-new-fact').click(function() {
en tu código y que importabas la librería y creí que lo usabas. Vainilla JS entonces.

Comment: @amenadiel por que no funciona con js puro `var iteracion=0;
function modificar(estado){
        var h2 = document.querySelectorAll(".stepwizard-row > .stepwizard-step >.btn");
        for (hh of h2) {
            hh.classList.add('btn-default');
            hh.classList.remove('btn-primary');   
        }
var h1 = document.getElementById("stepwizard-row");
            var hijo=h1.childNodes[estado];
            var boton=hijo.childNodes[1];
            boton.classList.add('btn-primary');
}
 $('#add-new-fact').click(function() {
iteracion++;
modificar(iteracion);
         });`

Comment: @Orici no se de donde sacas vanillajs, yo necesito sin librerias

Comment: Es bueno que quieres hacerlo con vanilla JavaScript, ¡así tendrás una buena base del lenguaje y lo entederás!

Comment: @hubman en realidad es sólo por comodidad que lo expresé con jQuery (que ya estabas usando).

Comment: @hubman a JS ahora se le llama Vainilla JS, para diferenciarlo de todo lo demás que hay por ahí basado en JS y que la gente suele emplear indistintamente cuando se requiere JS. Una de las cosas que pasaba era precisamente esto, que pedías o buscabas  algo en JS y no había manera, todo era jQuery y cosas similares. Creo que inicialmente surgió como defensa del lenguaje, hay una web y todo: http://vanilla-js.com/ comparando el uso de JS con librerías JS, como una más, pero mejor claro.

Answer (score 1):

En realidad solo debes hacer unas cuantas cosas:

1. Obtener el índice respecto al padre del botón activo.
2. Eliminar la clase `btn-primary` del botón activo.
3. Sumar 1 al índice para obtener el siguiente botón.
   3.1 En caso el índice ha llegado al final, se resetea.
4. Agregar la clase `btn-primary` al botón.

```js
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.stepwizard-row .btn');
let send = document.getElementById('add-new-fact');

send.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let button = [].filter.call(buttons, button => (
    button.classList.contains('btn-primary')
  ))[0];
  let index = [].indexOf.call(buttons, button);

  button.classList.remove('btn-primary');
  button.classList.add('btn-default');
  index = index < 2 ? index : -1;
  
  [].forEach.call(buttons, button => (
     button.className = 'btn btn-default btn-circle'
  ));
  
  buttons[index + 1].classList.remove('btn-default');
  buttons[index + 1].classList.add('btn-primary');
});
```

```css
body{margin:40px;}

.stepwizard-step p {
    margin-top: 10px;    
}

.stepwizard-row {
    display: table-row;
}

.stepwizard {
    display: table;     
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.stepwizard-step button[disabled] {
    opacity: 1 !important;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100) !important;
}

.stepwizard-row:before {
    top: 14px;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    content: " ";
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    z-order: 0;
    
}

.stepwizard-step {    
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}

.btn-circle {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center !imporant;
  padding: 0 !important;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 30px !important;
  border-radius: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">


 <div class="stepwizard">
    <div class="stepwizard-row" id="stepwizard-row">
        <div class="stepwizard-step">
            <button id="uno" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-circle">1</button>
            <p>Registro #1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="stepwizard-step">
            <button id="dos" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle">2</button>
            <p>Registro #2</p>
        </div>
        <div class="stepwizard-step">
            <button id="tres" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle">3</button>
            <p>Registro #3</p>
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>

<a id='add-new-fact' href='#'>enviar</a>
```